# Using Ubuntu on a Mac : same trackpad experience?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, mac, multi-touch

I've just installed Ubuntu and I like it but is there any way to have the same trackpad experience as on Mac OS ? 
I mean on Mac OS when I put two fingers on the trackpad and move one of them the cursor move. When I'm on Ubuntu it stops the cursor. Are there any drivers or something like that to enhance my experience ? thanks

edit as @ianorlin noticed, I forgot to mention my Macbook. It is a 2010 white Macbook. Thank @ianorlin

Comment: It would be a bit useful to know which macbook you have.

Comment: you're right ! 2010 white Macbook